# Choose the best model

Tags: neural-networks, classification, predictive-models, overfitting

I'm doing leave one out validation (I take a pair, that include each class) for my data set, the problem is binary clasify for spectres, using NN, on train i get 85% accuracy, even in the class with less samples, on test a 60% accuracy, but my doubt is how i should train my last model to predict the test set, in some cases the pair is predicted like the image  [image]

In other cases overfits on the class with more samples, but the predictions on train gaves those result beacause we are using a checkpoint on val_loss [image]

How i train my model to not overfit like some cases and get the best performance for test data?